# What does `filter(category_slug=category)` mean?

Tags: django-queryset, wagtail

I have below `models.py` setup,

```
class PostList(RoutablePageMixin, Page):
    template = "Post_List.html"
    intro = RichTextField(blank=True)
    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel("intro")
        ]

    subpage_types = [
        "PostDetail",
    ]

    parent_page_type = [
        "HomePage",
    ]

    def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)
        context['posts'] = self.posts    
        context['post_list'] = self
        return context

    def get_posts(self):
        return PostList.objects.descendant_of(self).live()


    @route(r'^tag/(?P<tag>[-\w]+)/$')
    def post_by_tag(self, request, tag, *args, **kwargs):
        self.search_type = 'tag'
        self.search_term = tag
        self.posts = self.get_posts().filter(tag__slug=tag)
        return Page.serve(self, request, *args, **kwargs)

    @route(r'^category/(?P<category>[-\w]+)/$')
    def post_by_category(self, request, category, *args, **kwargs):
        self.search_type = 'category'
        self.search_term = category
        self.posts = self.get_posts().filter(category__slug=category)
        return Page.serve(self, request, *args, **kwargs)

    @route(r'^$')
    def post_list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.posts = self.get_posts()
        return Page.serve(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
```

**Q:** I do not understand what does category__slug mean in `filter(category__slug=category)`?
According to [field lookup in Django official doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#id4), I never see filter like this, only see xxx__gt or xxx__exact etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do not understand what does category__slug mean in `filter(category__slug=category)`.

It means we are filtering on the `slug` field of the `category` of the post objects. `__slug` is thus *not* a lookup, it is a field of the `Category` model. The model thus will look like:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField()
    # …

class Post(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # …
```

We thus will make a query that looks like:

```
SELECT post.*
FROM post
INNER JOIN category ON post.category_id = category_id
WHERE category.slug = value-of-category-variable
```

Comment: thanks for reply. I never saw this syntax documented anywhere. Any official documents on this ? I only saw `xxx__gt` or `xxx__exact` etc documented in Django official documents.

Comment: @TianYan: yes, the [*making queries* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/) discusses this at length.